# Finding the ratio of two persons time spent driving to a meeting

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Mark and pat drive separately to a meeting. mark's average driving speed is $1/3rd$ greater than pat's and mark drives twice as many miles as pat. 
What is ratio of number of hours mark spends driving to the meeting to the number of hours pat spends driving to meeting

Comment: What do you know about the relationship between distance, speed and time?

Comment: Consider $V=\frac St$, $V_{Marc}=\frac43 V_{Pat}$ and $S$ is constant.

Comment: S = D / T T = D / S D = T * S Speed is equal to distance over time. Speed is directly proportional to distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$m_s$: Mark's driving speed, $\quad p_s$: Pat's driving speed

$$m_s = p_s + \frac 13 p_s = \frac 43 p_s\tag{1}$$

$m_d$: Distance Mark drives, $\quad p_d$: distance Pat drives

$$m_d = 2 p_d\tag{2}$$

$m_t$: Time Mark spends driving, $\quad p_t$: Time Pat spends driving

$$\large\frac{m_{t}}{p_{t}} \ = \ \frac{m_{d}/m_s}{p_d/p_s}\; = \; \frac{m_{d}}{p_d} \cdot \frac{p_s}{m_s} $$ $$= \frac{2p_d}{p_d}\cdot \frac{p_s}{\frac 43 p_s}\tag{substitution (1), (2)}$$ $$ = 2\cdot \frac{1}{4/3} =  \frac 32\tag{cancel units and evaluate}$$

Comment: Okay , from the above information i can say ratio of 3:2

Comment: ms=ps+1/3ps=4/3ps.  Why you took ps+1/3ps , instead of ms = 1/3ps

Comment: Because mark's speed is $1/3$ **greater than** pat's speed: so it is pat's speed plus 1/3 of pat's speed = 4/3 pat's speed.

Comment: ohh ! This interpretation was getting wrong ...

Comment: Can you see how unit's cancel out nicely: the important thing here is understanding the *relationships* of mark's and pat's speed, and that of the distance each commutes, and being able to reduce the number of "unknowns, in the end.

Comment: seriously awesome explanation @amWhy

Comment: Thank you, SSK. You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: very nice discourse! +1

Answer (score 1):

Many problems are made simpler by producing a comparison ratio; in fact, this problem specifically asks for one.  Since the time $ \ T \ $ to cover a distance $ \ D \ $ at a constant speed $ \ v \ $ is given by $ \ T = \frac{D}{v} \ $ , we can write

$$ \frac{T_{Mark}}{T_{Pat}} \ = \ \frac{D_{Mark}/v_{Mark}}{D_{Pat}/v_{Pat}} \ = \ \frac{D_{Mark}}{D_{Pat}} \cdot \frac{v_{Pat}}{v_{Mark}}  \ . $$

You would now interpret the information given in the problem in order to use this appropriately.

Comment: Okay Vmark = 1/3 and Dmark =2 , so it will be 2/Dpat * Vpat/ 1/3

Comment: Mark's speed is 1/3 _greater_ than Pat's, so $ \ v_{Mark} = v_{Pat} \ + \ \frac{1}{3} \cdot v_{Pat} = \frac{4}{3} \cdot v_{Pat} \ . $  Also, $ \ D_{Mark} = 2 \cdot D_{Pat} . $

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are to use $x$'s and $y$'s and $t$'s. This answer is intended to show that (in this case) we can dispense with these things. But you should write up a more conventional solution.

The planet that Mark and Pat live on was not specified. So we can suppose that in the units used on that planet, Pat's speed is $3$ and Mark's is $4$. We can also suppose that in the units used on that planet, Mark drives a distance $12$, so Pat drives $6$. Mark then takes $3$ units of time, and Pat takes $2$.

Comment: Very nice approach

Answer (score 0):

We know that distance=average speed x time. 
 Let's put this as $d=v\cdot t \;$
and denote:
$$\begin{align}
& Mark's\; average\; speed: v_M \\
& Pat's\; average\; speed:v_P \\
& distance\; driven\; by Pat\; :d \\
& time\; taken\; by\; Mark:t_M \\
& time\; taken\; by\; Pat:t_P \\
& ratio\; of\; number\; of\; hours\; mark\; spends\; driving\; to\; the\; meeting\; to\; the\; number\; of\; hours\; \\ 
& pat\; spends\; driving\; to\; meeting\;=\frac{t_M}{t_P} \\
\end{align}$$
Hence 
$\;v_M=\frac{2d}{t_M} \; and \;v_P=\frac{d}{t_P} $

$$\begin{align}  
 \frac{2d}{t_M} & =\frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{d}{t_P}  \\
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}  
 \frac{t_M}{t_P} & =\frac{3}{2}  \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: you not considered the distance of mark which is actually twice of pat .

Comment: Thanks @SSK for pointing this out. The MathJax formatting was actually confusing me that I forgot about the distance being different.